# can I wire up an npm run cmd as a gruntfile task?

Tags: angular, powershell, npm, gruntjs

I've updated the package.json in my site root dir with the following "scripts" hook:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ngDeployDev": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ../../Scripts/ng-build-deploy/ngDeployDev.ps1"
  }
```

I can execute this via cmd as "npm run ngDeployDev".  Can I configure my gruntfile.js to call this cmd via a task?  For example, I'd like to configure my gruntfile.js so that my VS2017 Task Runner Explorer displays a task of "ngDeployDev" in the gruntfile tree.  Running this task should in turn exec "npm run ngDeployDev"

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a need for what I described in my original post. The following vsix will integrate package.json script options in a treeview in the VS "Taskk Runner Explorer" on the same level as the gruntfile.js tasks treeview:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner